# How to prevent Kendo Grid (ASP.NET MVC wrapper) from escaping HTML link in bound data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo data grid in an ASP.NET MVC application. My first column of data that is bound to the grid contains a string which includes an HTML link. When the grid loads in the browser, the HTML markup is escaped and visible, rather than rendering as a hyperlink.

How can I change this behavior?

```
<div>
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ManageProjectViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.OrganizationName).Width(150).Format("");
        columns.Bound(c => c.Name).Width(150);
        columns.Bound(c => c.AdministratorName).Width(150);
        columns.Bound(c => c.SponsorName).Width(150);
    })
    .Selectable(selectable => selectable
        .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
            .Events(events => events.Change("onChange").DataBound("initGrid"))
    .Sortable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("ListProjects", "Organization"))
        .ServerOperation(false)
    )

)
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use .Encoded(false); on the column that you want to display raw html